# MongoDB: how to create a new database

Tags: mongodb, nosql

After installation, `test`,`admin` and `local` are the default database.
As per the MongoDB tutorial, when we insert data in collection a database will be listed in `show dbs` command.
For a specific purpose, I want to create a new database but I did not find any information about creating a new database. I executed a command like `create db dbname` or `create database dbname`. For both of the statement I got below error:
**SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Can I know what are the steps to create a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just execute on shell "use dbname"
When you insert the first document on any collection you will see the db with "show dbs"

Comment: It worked now. Really its strange and I don't know why it didn't work earlier. I already tried by `use dbname` but it was giving error.